# Fishpig Wordpress Magento integration - get the list of all authors

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2 and Fishpig Wordpress full integration extension v. 2.5.0.9

I would like to list **all blog authors** on my WP integrated Magento Blog.
I want it to be done automatically, so the list is updated whenever a new WP author appears.

Anyone has a suggestion how I could extract an array of authors and their information (name, description, etc) using Fishpig functionality?

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: I looked through all the Fishpig code - but I could not see any possibility to do that. I imagine I have to create new .php files inside Fishpig's /app/code/ - but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve a collection of authors using the following code:

```
<?php $authors = Mage::getResourceModel('wordpress/user_collection') ?>
```

You can then list through these as follows:

```
<?php $authors = Mage::getResourceModel('wordpress/user_collection') ?>
<?php if (count($authors) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach($authors as $author): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $author->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $author->getDisplayName() ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped a lot. If anybody will need this, here are 2 other methods to extract Description and Avatar of the Author:
`$author->getMetaValue('description')`, 
`$author->getGravatarUrl(70)`